# Select first child of div without using first-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to select the first child of a parent div, but I have some constraints: the div I want to select has a very general class name, and I don't have access to the markup to give it another class. Since it has such a general class name, if I use first-child, my changes will apply to unrelated elements on the page. It also has a sibling with the same type and class name:

```
<div class="parent-div">
    <div class="extremely-general-class">I want to change this one</div>
    <div class="extremely-general-class">And not change this one</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to select only the first child of a parent div, but without using first-child? If I use

```
parent-div > general-class
```

then it will apply to both sibling divs.

Comment: "Since it has such a general class name, if I use first-child, my changes will apply to unrelated elements on the page." I don't quite understand. Can you provide more concrete examples of :first-child potentially matching the wrong elements?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I'm not seeing the argument as to why `.parent-div > div:first-child` wouldn't work.

Comment: There are other divs on the page that also have `.extremely-general-class` and are the first child of their parent.

Comment: Does .parent-div > .general-class:first-child not work for you?

Comment: @HeatherStone I realize that. Is `.parent-div` plastered everywhere also? And you can't use `.parent-div > .general-class:first-child` because not all first child `.general-class` should be selected as a child of `.parent-div`? If not, `.parent-div > .general-class:first-child` should work as `.parent-div` is scoping the selector so that `> .general-class:first-child` will only be apply to the children of `.parend-div`. Do you understand the difference between `.general-class:first-child`, `.parent-div .general-class:first-child` and `.parent-div > .general-class:first-child`?

Comment: @hungerstar my previous comment was in response to @BoltClock. As it turns out, the reason `.parent-div > div:first-child` wasn't working was because the server was down, so no changes whatsoever were showing!

Comment: @HeatherStone if the server was down, how were you able to view your site?

Answer (score 0):

Answer would be nesting, like:

```
grand-grand-parent-div > grandparent-div > parent-div > general-class:first-child
```

and so on, as long as the structure does not repeat.

Another idea which came to my mind was using `:not()` selector, but that's the case only if other divs u don't want to style have something in common that to-be-styled doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

You can select the first child using

```
general-class:nth-child(1)
```

that is, as you asked, not using first-child